# flutter ! About getting phone language settings?

Tags: flutter

I want to get the local mobile phone language, simplified Chinese or English, but the function `localeResolutionCallback` always returns `en` under ios but the mobile phone is simplified Chinese, how to solve this problem?

flutter information:

```
Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76,
    locale zh-Hans-CN)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
    ✗ Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

The newly created app also has this problem:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      supportedLocales: [//传入支持的语种数组
        const Locale('en', 'EN'), // English
        const Locale('zh', 'CN'), //
      ],
      localeResolutionCallback: (locale, locales) {
        print('cacasasc, ${locale.languageCode} ${locales}');
        if (locale.languageCode == 'zh') {
          return Locale('zh', 'CN');
        } else {
          return Locale('en', 'EN');
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

log:

```
flutter: cacasasc, en
```

Comment: Is it working on android and have you checked this?  https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#tracking-the-locale-the-locale-class-and-the-localizations-widget

Comment: It is working on Android,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is supposed to work fine on Android.

**For IOS**, you need to do something very simple. Open Info.plist which is located in `project_name/ios/Runner/Info.plist` and add the languages you want to support like this:

```
  <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
  <array>
    <string>English</string>
    <string>es</string>
    <string>zh</string>
  </array>
```

So, each language will be between string tags and the whole code will be above `<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>`.